# How to maintain relation between redis and mysql

Tags: mysql, redis, foreign-keys, distributed-system, distributed-transactions

I have two tables `User` and `Role` in **mysql**. There is a `many-to-one` relationship from `User` table to `Role` table. Now I want to move the `Role` table to **redis**. If so, then the `foreign-key` relationship is broken. Is there any way to maintain the relationship so that my queries and transactions both go fine ?

Answer (score 0):

Redis is KV so don't use it for range query between multiple keys.

You can use list/zset/set(depends on your need) for Role - Users relationship.

And if you want to keep transactions between Redis and mysql, it will take a lot of extra works(like distributed transaction systems).